# How to use computed values inside a function that demands an array

Tags: arrays, excel

There's a handy Excel function called `SMALL` that lets you find the n-th smallest value from an array.  For example: `SMALL({35;10;5000;6},2)` = `10`, the second smallest number in the set.

You could use this function by referencing an array of cells (`SMALL(A1:A10,2)`) or you can write an array of constant values in the formula directly (`SMALL({1;2;3},2)`).

Is there a way to write an array of computed values directly in the formula?  It should look something like this, if using `RAND` to generate the values:

```
 SMALL({RAND();RAND();RAND()},2)
```

but Excel doesn't allow that.

How can you use a function (like `RAND`) inside another function that demands an array (like `SMALL`)?

---

Yes, I'm aware that the usual solution would be to put the computed values in their own individual cells, then just use that array as the input of `SMALL`.  It would be great if I could do this all inside a single cell.

Comment: Since xl2010 there is a handy function called AGGREGATE that reproduces SMALL with psuedo-array processing (like SUMPRODUCT) and allows for discarding errorS and/or hidden cells.

Comment: btw, you might find Extremis (Dr. Who S10E06) interesting.

Comment: ANy reason why you cannot use a range of cells with the RAND function and get the SMALL's from those?

Comment: @jkpieterse, the spreadsheet I'm working on has a rather complex structure.  It would be much easier if this task could be done in a single cell.

Comment: I understand, but doing all in a single cell does not necessarily help making clear what goes on in your spreadsheet :-) You can always add a sheet to hold the rand's.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer as you may know is that you would use an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d).

This is a bit difficult to illustrate with RAND(), but if you take a more normal function like SQRT, the usage would be

```
=SMALL(SQRT({9,4,1}),1)
```

so instead of providing a single argument to SQRT, you are providing a list of arguments which it is going to work through one at a time and return an array of 3 elements {3,2,1} which is passed to SMALL to evaluate.

If the same list of numbers was in (say) A1:A3, you would need to enter this as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=SMALL(SQRT(A1:A3),1)
```

But as pointed out by @Jeeped, it's often more convenient to use AGGREGATE

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,SQRT(A1:A3),1)
```

As far as I know, you can't reproduce this behaviour with RAND because it is one of the few Excel functions that takes no arguments.

If you really did want to generate an array of random numbers r where 0<=r<1 , you would have to do something like this

```
=SMALL((RANDBETWEEN({0,0,0},10^20-1)/10^20),1)
```

i.e. use RANDBETWEEN with an arbitrarily large upper limit.